# Regular Expression Issue in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have searched everywhere and I cannot find what I am doing wrong.

I have this regular expression: `^(\[\[).+(\]\])` that I want to match for this data that starts just at the beginning of the line as shown below (I do not want to match anything but the things starting at the beginning of a line):

```
[[match this]]   [[don't match this]]
{{Link GA|es}}
{{Link FA|ca}}
```

And for some reason it is not matching anything in Java (or other regex "testers" such as regexpal.com). By "in Java" i mean with the String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) method in the Java String API.

But, if I omit the `^` and just have `(\[\[).+(\]\])` it matches fine at the beginning of the line, but also matches inline instances which I do not want.

Can anyone point out what the error is here? Thank you

Comment: `^\[\[(.+?)\]\]` e.g., stop being greedy. Assuming the things in the curly braces *shouldn't* be matched. And you actually want to capture what's *in* the brackets, but you can do whatever you want with the parens.

Comment: Actually, I want to completely remove the braces and everything in them. So in the example code snipped, it would remove the the first `[[match this]]` and the first line would just read `[[don't match this]]`. Also, I tried putting that regex in regexpal.com on that same data set and it still does not match. But again it does match all instances of it without the `^` in the front.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to a) build your regex object and b) apply it to your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` means "start of string", not "start of line", unless you use the `Pattern.MULTILINE` (or `(?m)`) option when building the regex. Also, you should be using a lazy quantifier (as pointed out by Dave Newton in his comment).

Finally, don't forget to double the backslashes:

```
String result = subject.replaceAll("(?m)^\\[\\[.+?\\]\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.+` is greedy, in that it will match everything it can (here, matching everything up to the last `\]\]`

To stop this behaviour just add a `?` to make it non-greedy

```
    ^\[\[.+?\]\]
```

Will match `[[` then look for any characters until it finds the first occurrence of `]]`

Answer (score -2):

`(\[\[).+(\]\]){1}+` {1}+ that mean exactly one time's [improve link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: `{1}` is a no-op (because matching something exactly once is the default). And adding a `+` afterwards would make that quantifier possessive (which is useless with a fixed number of matches).